# docker-compose gives mongo error about not owning the data folder

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

Based on the following files:
`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:8-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN apk add --no-cache tar

WORKDIR /app/

COPY package*.json /app/
COPY bower.json /app/

RUN npm i
RUN npm i -g bower
RUN bower install --allow-root

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

`docker-compose-yml`

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  node:
    container_name: nodetube
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "49161:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app/
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./upload:/app/upload
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - MONGODB_DOCKER_URI=mongodb://nodetube-mongo:27017/nodetube
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mongo
    command: npm start
    networks:
      - nodetube-network

  mongo:
    container_name: nodetube-mongo
    image: mongo:3.6
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27011:27017"
    networks:
      - nodetube-network

  redis:
    container_name: nodetube-redis
    image: redis
    networks:
      - nodetube-network

networks:
  nodetube-network:
    driver: bridge
```

`.dockerignore`

```
.*
docker-compose.yml
*.md

node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

Running `$ docker-compose up --build` gives me an error:

`nodetube-mongo | 2020-01-06T19:33:08.815+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating`

I'm not a Docker expert, how can I get this to work? Thanks

On my local machine if I run `$ ls -al /data`
I receive:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     wheel    128 May 13  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x   33 root     wheel   1056 Apr 11  2019 ..
drwxrwxrwx  432 anthony  wheel  13824 Jan  6 12:21 db
drwxr-xr-x  385 anthony  wheel  12320 May 13  2018 db2
```

```
anthony at Anthonys-MacBook-Pro in /data/db
$ ls -al
total 17565016
drwxrwxrwx  432 anthony  wheel      13824 Jan  6 12:21 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     wheel        128 May 13  2018 ..
-rw--w--w-    1 anthony  wheel         48 May 13  2018 WiredTiger
-rw--w--w-    1 anthony  wheel         21 May 13  2018 WiredTiger.lock
-rw--w--w-    1 anthony  wheel       1088 Jan  6 12:21 WiredTiger.turtle
-rw--w--w-    1 anthony  wheel    1216512 Jan  6 12:21 WiredTiger.wt
-rw--w--w-    1 anthony  wheel       4096 Jan  6 12:20 WiredTigerLAS.wt
```

Comment: Look at the  ./data/db  directory on your host, there must be something unusual about the permissions there.

Comment: @RobertMoskal updated my question

Comment: Why are you developing off the root of your file system instead of in your home directory!? What are the permissions inside of the db directory?

Comment: @RobertMoskal
Not sure I suppose I just am using the stock configuration. And I just added more info

Comment: If you give docker an empty db directory, what happens?

Comment: Sorry I know you're referencing this line `- ./data/db:/data/db` but what should I change it to? I actually had some folks that I am working on a project with make this file so I'm not super familiar with docker-compose. @RobertMoskal

Comment: You are mounting the /data/db directory from the host under the same path inside the container.  I'm guessing you want to mount the mongo datafiles in there.

Try this in that directory chmod ugo+rw *

Comment: you '/data' is root, try to `chown -R anthony /data`. Seems permissions issue

Comment: @Valijon now I have the permissions fixed but I get another error: Uncaught Exception:  { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]